# SQL to select only users that are related, in subtractive method

Tags: mysql, sql, t-sql, stored-procedures

Consider these tables: (just examples)

```
Users: (all users)
userid
username

Class_Detail: (users and which class they are in)
userid_fk
classid_fk (relates to a class lookup table)


Sport_Detail: (sports each user plays)
userid_fk
sportid_fk (relates to a sport lookup table)


Resources_Detail: (resources that are assigned to users based on class and sport)
resourceid_fk
foreign_key (classid_fk or sportid_fk)
foreign_key_type (class designation or sport designation)
```

A user will log into the site, and get Resources that an instructor has assigned them.  The instructor may assign resources to entire classes, or entire sports, or only specific classes that are for specific sports.

It could be that a instructor assign Resource 1 to all of Class 1, so everyone in Class 1 should see the resources available to them when they log in.  And, the instructor may assign Resource 2 to all Sport 1, so everyone in Sport 1 should see Resource 2 when they log in.  And, the instructor may assign Resource 3 to Class 2 but only if they are associated with Sport 2.  The SQL needs to be subtractive, meaning, it needs to filter based on class, sport, and compound class and sport.

Example data in Resources:

```
resourceid_fk | foreign_key | foreign_key_type
1               cl1             class
2               cl1             class
3               sp1             sport 
4               sp1             sport
5               cl2             class
5               sp2             sport
5               cl3             class
6               cl2             class

In the above:
Resource 1 is available to only everyone in Class 1.
Resource 2 is available to only everyone in Class 1.
Resource 3 is available to only everyone in Sport 1.
Resource 4 is available to only everyone in Sport 1.
Resource 5 is available to only users in Class 2 ONLY IF THEY ARE ALSO IN SPORT 2. (Subtractive, not additive).
Resource 5 is available to everyone in Class 3.
Resource 6 is available to only everyone in Class 2.
```

Example, if a user is in Class 2 AND Sport 2 (based on Class_Detail and Sport_Detail), when they log in they would see:

Resource 5 and 6

However, if the user is in Class 2, but not Sport 2, they would only see Resource 6, because Resource 5 requires the you have to be Class 2 and Sport 2 to see it.

Hoping to be able to do this all in one query, but a proc if necessary.  This is **for mySQL database**, but same logic would apply for SQL Server.  I should be able to convert any ideas from SQL to mySQL as needed.  It's the logic for this that is most important.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: "This is mySQL." - Then why did you tag [tsql]? Read the description: "T-SQL ... Do not use this tag for MySQL ..."

Comment: Because the database is somewhat irrelevant for this question, as it's more about SQL and DB querying, potentially stored proc, in general, and someone with TSQL experience would be able to help.

Comment: At least a "stored proc" would be vendor specific. If you want a vendor agnostic solution, you can use the [sql] tag - But then don't expect someone to write a stored proc for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can have something like below:

Instead of resource detail table, keep two tables

1. class_resource
   classId, resource_id
2. sport_resource
   sport_id, resource_id

Query can look something like:

(select resource_id from class_detail cd inner join class_resource cr on cd.class_id = cr.class_id and cd.user_id = ? ) UNION (select resource_id from sport_detail sd inner join sport_resource sr on sd.sport_id = sr.sport_id and sd.user_id =?)

This design might help in future when you can start directly assigning resources to users. You will add another union.

If scalability becomes an issue you keep more normalized form and save user_resource mapping as well.

Comment: The table structure is not changeable.  This is an adopted DB, with a ton of code dependencies.  Also, that answer does not address subtractive, where only available to end user if it's singularly shared with the class the user is in, or if shared with only specific class that is also only sport the user is in.

Comment: Ok. I got your point that database can really not be changed. Can you explain how  for "resource 5" substractive rule is applicable to class2 only and not to class3.

Comment: Resource 5 requires the you have to be in Class 2 and in Sport 2 to see it.  However, Resource 5 is also for Class 3, and has no sport requirement, so it goes to ALL of Class 3.  Think of class as like a skill level.  All 2nd level users in Soccer should see resource 5, and all 3rd level users should see resource 5, regardless of if they play soccer.

Comment: Exactly my question, where is class and sport relationship? How do i know sport2 has to be linked to class2 or class3? from where does that information come?

Comment: Class and sport are not linked.  It's the user that may be associated with both, one, or neither.  A user could be in Class 3 and not play any sport.  But, they would still get assigned resources that are ONLY for Class 3. However, if the resource is assigned to Class 3 AND Sport 2, then only users that are both Class 3 and Sport 2 would see the resource. Sport is subtractive of Class, if Sport and Class exist for the resource.